# "TypeError: string indices must be integers" when using cleaned_data

Tags: python, django, cleaned-data

The error occurs here:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            clean = form.cleaned_data

            username = clean['username']
            email = clean['email']
            password = clean['password']
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            new_user.save()
            new_account = Account(user=new_user, email=email)
            new_account.save()
```

At the `username = clean['username']` line. I've been able to use this exact line successfully in other places without issue. Why is it an issue now?

Comment: Can you please add the traceback to the question and the code of RegisterForm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably returning the wrong thing from the form's `clean()` method - you should be returning the full `self.cleaned_data` dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `cleaned_data` is giving you a string, not a dictionary.

As a string can only be indexed by numbers, it's giving you this error.

Try printing the value to see what is going on.

Comment: Printing it out shows that `clean` only contains `password`. Why isn't the rest of the form loading into the dictionary?